# Insert using LINQ to SQL in ASP.NET - Error

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq-to-sql, sql-insert

I want to insert data by using LINQ to SQL in ASP.NET. My codes is shown below. But when i click the 'Kaydet' button then the error occurred. how can i fix it ?

```
 protected void btnKaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
            DBDataContext dbnew = new DBDataContext();
            tbl_Kullanicilar user = new tbl_Kullanicilar();

            user.Kullanici_adi = txtKullaniciAdi.Text;
            user.Profil_isim = txtİsim.Text;
            user.Mail = txtEmail.Text;
            user.Kullanici_soyisim = txtSoyisim.Text;
            user.Kullanici_Sifre = txtSifre.Text;
            user.Durum = drpDurum.Text;
            user.Tur = drpTür.Text;
            user.Telefon = txtTelefon.Text;

        dbnew.tbl_Kullanicilars.InsertOnSubmit(user);
        dbnew.SubmitChanges();               
    }
```

[image: the error]

[image]

> Error with English :
>   Invalid postback or recall independent variable. Event validation was enabled using  or <% @ Page EnableEventValidation = "true"%> in the configuration. This feature verifies that, for security reasons, the return or recall events arguments result from the server control handling them at startup. If the data is valid and as expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method to save the return or recall data for validation.
>   Explanation: An unhandled exception occurred while executing the current web request. Please observe the stack trace to find out more about the error and where it originates in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or recall independent variable. Event validation was enabled using  or <% @ Page EnableEventValidation = "true"%> in the configuration. This feature verifies that, for security reasons, the return or recall events arguments result from the server control handling them at startup. If the data is valid and as expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method to save the return or recall data for validation.
>   Source Error:
>   An exception was thrown when the current web request was executed. Information about the source and location of the exception can be determined using the following exception stack trace.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image.  It would also be very helpful to translate the error message to English.

Comment: the post is updated.

Comment: Its the error due to the request validation failure coz of the data entered in the form which is being submitted. Can you tell us what data you entered in the form? The invalid data could be some html contents or scripts.

Comment: i updated the post, please check again.

Comment: Looks like issue is different then what I mentioned. Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223397(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I solved this error. I am new in stackoverflow so i don't know what should i do. Should i share the solution to being helpful to other people ? or should i delete this post ? Can anyone help me please

Comment: The error you show is f100% sure not created by the Linq code on your button.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error and i want to share the solution to being helpful other people. the solution is that ;

if you get this error, you should add this attribute begin of the example.aspx

```
enableEventValidation="false"
```

As a result, it should be

```
<%@ Page Title=""  enableEventValidation="false" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ProjectMenagement.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Kişiler_kişiekle.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Kişiler_kişiekle" %>
```

Comment: this is not really solving the problem but ignoring it.

Comment: i know , i agree with you but when i added the attribute to project , the problem is solved.